# Multiple values in column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table which contains a field with multiple values.
I familiar with the "set" type, but the problem is that I don't know exactly all the value in advanced.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them as **comma-separated** values (strings) in the column, and use the `find_in_set` function to query (in case you want to).

**ADD:**

You could later query as shown below:

For instance, to search for all rows which have `value1` as a value in that column, use this:

```
SELECT T1.column
FROM Table T1 
WHERE find_in_set('value1', T1.column) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the programming language you will use You may want to serialize the data and use  a VARCHAR (long) or BLOB type. This way, you can put almost anything to your field like an array with multiple data type. In php the description is simple :

> serialize — Generates a storable representation of a value